# Spring framework updating entity email error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have one problem with my login/registration program.

When I'm trying to update employee information fields without changing email, I have an exception that email already exists, but when I'm changing email field and some others, then new employee record is created with this new email. I would appreciate any help, because I'm completely blank about this.

P.S. I have read innumerable amount of quite similar questions, but none of them helped me.

**Employee entity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; 
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
     
    @Column(name = "department", nullable = false)
    private String department;
    
    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private String birthDate;
    
    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="employees_roles",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Role entity**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

**EmployeeService implementation**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
     
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    public void saveAndFlush(EmployeeDto employeeDto) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName(employeeDto.getFirstName());
        employee.setLastName(employeeDto.getLastName());
        employee.setBirthDate(employeeDto.getBirthDate());
        employee.setPhoneNumber(employeeDto.getPhoneNumber());
        employee.setDepartment(employeeDto.getDepartment());
        employee.setEmail(employeeDto.getEmail());
        
        employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(employeeDto.getPassword()));
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        
        if(role == null){
            role = checkRoleExist();
        }
        
        employee.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee findByEmail(String email) {
        return employeeRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<EmployeeDto> findAll() {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAll();
        return employees.stream()
                .map((employee) -> convertEntityToDto(employee))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private EmployeeDto convertEntityToDto(Employee employee){
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto();
        employeeDto.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
        employeeDto.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
        employeeDto.setPhoneNumber(employee.getPhoneNumber());
        employeeDto.setBirthDate(employee.getBirthDate());
        employeeDto.setDepartment(employee.getDepartment());
        employeeDto.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
        return employeeDto;
    }

    private Role checkRoleExist() {
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }

}
```

**Dto**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeDto
{
    private Long id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email should not be empty")
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password should not be empty")
    private String password;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Department should not be empty")
    private String department;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Birth date should not be empty")
    private String birthDate;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Phone number should not be empty")
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

**Edit controller for better understanding**

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{email}")
    public String getEdit(@PathVariable String email, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", employeeService.findByEmail(email));
         
            if(email == null) {
                throw new UserNotFoundException(email);
            }
            
        return "edit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/edit/{email}")
    public String postEdit(@PathVariable String email, @ModelAttribute("user") EmployeeDto empDto, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    //      if (HelperController.hasErrors(result, model)) {
    //      return "edit";
    //  }
        employeeService.findByEmail(email);
        employeeService.saveAndFlush(empDto);

        return "redirect:/all";
    }
```

**Employee details imlementation**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmail(email);
            if(employee != null) {
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                        employee.getEmail(), employee.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(employee.getRoles()));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn't exists"); 
            }
        }
    
        private Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection <Role> roles) {
                    Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRoles = roles.stream()
                            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    return mapRoles;
        }
}
```

**Repositories**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
    Employee findByEmail(String email);
}

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Role findByName(String name);
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Duplicate key values ​​violate uniqueness constraint "uk_j9xgmd0ya5jmus09o0b8pqrpb"
  Detail: The key (email)=(d@gmail.com) already exists.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3288) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3898) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:653) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:283) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy109.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy109.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:610) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy113.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.model.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl.saveAndFlush(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.controller.EmployeeController.postEdit(EmployeeController.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:906) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
```

Comment: In case of update, you should read the existing user first, change the fields and save the user again

Comment: @Jens Could you explain your answer for better understanding?

Comment: Call `findByEmail(String email);` to get the user from the DB, then set the changed field to the result of `findByEmail(String email);` and save it

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your reply, but this did'nt help or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Jens Maybe you can provide some code for your solution, it would help me a lot because I'm completely stuck with this stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of update, you should read the existing user first, change the fields and save the user again:

```
public void saveAndFlush(EmployeeDto employeeDto) {
     Employee employee = findByEmail(employeeDto.getEmail);
     if (employee == null){
        employee = new Employee();
 employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(employeeDto.getPassword()));
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        
        if(role == null){
            role = checkRoleExist();
        }
        
        employee.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
     }
    employee.setFirstName(employeeDto.getFirstName());
    employee.setLastName(employeeDto.getLastName());
    employee.setBirthDate(employeeDto.getBirthDate());
    employee.setPhoneNumber(employeeDto.getPhoneNumber());
    employee.setDepartment(employeeDto.getDepartment());
    employee.setEmail(employeeDto.getEmail());
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```